# Java - Using two classes with the same name in an Interface

Tags: java, eclipse, class, interface, namespaces

I need to use two classes with the same name but different namespaces (`foo.request.Response` and `bar.request.Response`) in an interface. In classes this can be achieved by using the full name with namespace :

```
public foo.request.Response method1() { [...]
public bar.request.Response method2() { [...]
```

But this does not seem to work in Interfaces.

What is the correct way of dealing with this problem ?

**Edit 1**
Error comes from Eclipse :

> foo cannot be resolved to a type

Interface code :

```
public interface ITestController {
    String method1(foo.request.Response response);
}
```

**I found the issue, it was not coming from the interface it was a simple mess-up in the dependencies. Thanks for your help ;)**

Comment: Any specific error you get?

Comment: Error is displayed by Eclipse and says 'foo cannot be resolved to a type'. It does not understand the full definition of the classe name

Comment: I updated the Q with the interface code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in interfaces, but care should be taken so that the implementing classes fully qualify the names in the same way.

Note that you can **not** choose which of the two classes when implement the interface. **It's the interface** that specifies *which* of the two classes is to be used when implementing the interface.

The code you've posted in your answer is messed up. If the two first methods belong to a class implementing `ITestController` then that class must also include an implementation for

```
public String method1(foo.request.Response response) { ... }
```

Comment: I know it was just an example. In fact the issue was coming from a problem in the dependencies ... Thanks for your help

Comment: Right. So, the answer to your question is indeed, *It works in interfaces, but care should be taken so that the implementing classes fully qualify the names in the same way.* :-)